# Как сохранить базу данных созданную в оперативной памяти?

Tags: python, sqlite3, база-данных

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить базу данных созданную в оперативной памяти следующим способом:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
```

по окончании работы с ней, в виде файла базы данных (.db) на жесткий диск?

З.Ы. Перерыл кучу статей в интернете и документацию, как это сделать так и не нашел. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А зачем создаваь БД в памяти? Создайте сразу в файл

    conn = sqlite3.connect( "temp.db" )

Только не забудьте conn.commit()

Comment: В оперативной памяти намного быстрее работает

Comment: Как насчет ramdisk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужны функции семейства `sqlite_backup_*`. [Тут](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) описание и подробный пример.

Comment: смотрите первый же пример из ссылки